# Can't change partitioning scheme for actors

Tags: azure-service-fabric

While playing with azure service fabric actors, here is the weird thing I've recently found out about - I can't change the default settings for partitioning. If I try to, say, set Named partitioning or change low/high key for UniformInt64, it gets overwritten each time I build my project in Visual Studio. There is no problem to do this for statefull service, it only happens with actors. No errors, no records in Event Log, no nothing... I've found just one single reference about the same problem on the Internet -

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4edbf0a3-307b-489f-b936-43af9a365a0a/applicationmanifestxml-overwritten-on-each-build?forum=AzureServiceFabric

But I haven't seen any explanations to that - neither on MSDN, nor in official documentation. Any ideas? Would it really be 'by design'?

P.S.

Executing just Powershell script to deploy the app does allow me to set the scheme the way I want it to. Still it's frustrating to not being able to do this in VS. Probably there is a good reason to that... it should be, right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reliable Services can be created with different partition schemes and
>   partition key ranges. The Actor Service uses the Int64 partitioning
>   scheme with the full Int64 key range to map actors to partitions.
>
> Every ActorId is hashed to an Int64, which is why the actor service
>   must use an Int64 partitioning scheme with the full Int64 key range.
>   However, custom ID values can be used for an ActorID, including GUIDs,
>   strings, and Int64s.
>
> When using GUIDs and strings, the values are hashed to an Int64.
>   However, when explicitly providing an Int64 to an ActorId, the Int64
>   will map directly to a partition without further hashing. This can be
>   used to control which partition actors are placed in.

([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform#service-fabric-partition-concepts-for-actors))

This ActorId => PartitionKey translation strategy doesn't work if your partitions are named.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, I understand that ActorID gets mapped to a particular partition, but still, since Actor is an extension over Stateful Service, why I can't do the same thing and change the scheme? Why we can't create an actor passing some string as ID and map it to a partition which has a name matching that very ID? And why VS doesn't show any error/warning and silently overrides my settings without giving me any clue?

Comment: if you have an actor name that matches a partition name you'll effectively limit your actor instance count to your partition count. This does not go well with the Actor theory (generally you'll have many actor instances). Why VS doesn't warn you, I don't know. You could create an issue for that here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues

Comment: Thanks! I have a number of tasks I want to spread across machines evenly, and the amount of tasks somewhere twice the amount of available nodes. So I thought about having a number of partitions set to the number of tasks, and when the time comes to run a task, I would have Actor instantiated with the ID of a given task name. Thus I could guarantee that I would have only one single task with a particular name at a given moment in time(Actors are thread-safe), and since partitions are distributed evenly across the cluster(by default), I would know that tasks are balanced. Does it make sense?

Comment: The number of partitions is not dynamic, changing it requires redeployment of your actorservice and dealing with the impact on existing state. It would make more sense to me to have a dynamic sized pool of Actors that monitor a Queue that holds tasks, and process them in their own time. Actors are distributed across partitions, so work is automatically balanced too. (provided there are more partitions than nodes)

Comment: Well, I thing I forgot to mention - I also would like to leverage the Reminder. When the app gets fired up, I spawn one actor per task with a configured reminder. There is no queue with the tasks, as I know beforehand what I need to do and when.  So, do I need to do anything about thinking how Actor ID should look like when I set up an actor or leave it up to the Service Fabric? I'm just worried to not have my actors spinning on a single node just because they don't consume any resources at the start time(when I wake them up to set up reminders).

Comment: if you use strings or guids or ActorId.CreateRandom to get ActorId instances your value will be hashed you the outcome should be a random partition. (so work load will be balanced) There's no guarantee that Actor instances won't be executed on one partition.